# Is deep copy possible in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Is deep copy possible in flex 4.5?

Comment: If your question is too short to post, don't try and game that by repeating it, **clarify it** by describing exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please dont ask objective questions?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a built in function for a deep copy in Flex.

```
import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;

var NewObj:Type = ObjectUtil.copy(Old);
```